# filtering based on array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

The below code worked 10 minutes ago and now I get error 1004: Autofilter method of Range class failed. Any idea why? I want to filter column C based on letter J - so filter only the values starting with J. After,I want to delete the hidden rows, but this doesn’t seem to work.please help

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim filterarray As Variant
Dim findarray As Variant
Dim MyLastRow1 As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

Sub test23()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("T&E Report")
    MyLastRow1 = Range("C100000").End(xlUp).Row
    findarray = Array("J")
    ReDim filterarray(0 To 0)

    j = 0

    For k = 0 To UBound(findarray)
        For i = 2 To MyLastRow1
            If InStr(ws.Cells(i, 3).Value, findarray(k)) > 0 Then
                filterarray(j) = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
                j = j + 1
                ReDim Preserve filterarray(0 To j)
            End If 
        Next i
    Next k

    ws.Range("$C$1:$C$" & MyLastRow1).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array(filterarray), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End sub
```

Comment: First, your `Dim` statements need to be within your `Sub`. If they are global you need to use `Public` to declare.

Comment: Is your range already filtered?

Comment: @Dean: You are right, all the variables should be declared within the Sub so that they are local. When you declare them at top of your code with `Dim`, they are global but only known within the module. If you declare them as `Global`, they are visible to all modules of your project.

Comment: You don't need the loop at all. Just filter using `"J*"` as the criterion.

Comment: @FunThomas thanks for that - was not aware that was the case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set your range of data to be filtered just to one column ("C"), but ask AutoFilter to set the filter according to the 3rd column of that range (so that would be column "E")

As column "E" is not part if the range to be filtered, you will get the 1004 runtime error. However, if you had already autofilter active that included column "E" (that means you have this triangle button visible on column E), the runtime error is not issued - maybe that's the reason the code worked 10 min ago.